# Downloading Media Files in Protractor e2e test case

Tags: javascript, protractor, download

I have used  [chromeOptions](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) object to accomplish downloading by setting default directory

```
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',            
    chromeOptions: {
      args: [
        '--no-sandbox', '--test-type=browser'
      ],
      prefs: {
        download: {
          prompt_for_download: false,
          default_directory: 'C:/absolute/path/to/tmp'
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Then I embedded a self-implemented download (Javascript)function and execute it by calling it in browser.executeScript('callFunc').

```
function download() {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'https://i.vimeocdn.com/portrait/58832_300x300');
  element.setAttribute('download', '58832_300x300');

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

browser.executeScript('download');
```

When I run my test case it simply open up the image in browser rather to download it in default directory. How can it be done?
**Note: If I automate to click anchor for downloading then it perfectly download to default directory**